# How to convert binary input into expected result?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have three characters say a,b,c . Here is the binary representation of a, b, c

```
a 001
b 010  
c 100
```

what I want is when someone provide  input as `011` , output should be `a,b`

Here is expected output

```
input   output
001     a
010     b
011     b,a
100     c
101     c,a
110     c,b
111     c,b,a
```

What is the efficient way to achieve this? I vaguely recalls there was some binary operator to achieve the same but i could not recollect this.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? And why the weird ordering - why is it "a,b" but "c,b,a" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `&` (bitwise and) operator and check if the result is not 0 to see if the integer is composed of a certain binary number.

`(011 & 001) != 0`

`(010 & 001) == 0`

`(010 & 010) != 0`

```
final int a = 0b001, b = 0b010, c = 0b100;
int val = 0b011;
boolean containsA = (val & a) != 0; // true
boolean containsC = (val & c) != 0; // false
```

Comment: Don't you mean &? It can be done with | but that would work differently